# linode instance size for hosting a RoR app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, ruby-on-rails-3.1

We are developing a RoR app on the smallest linode instance (512MB) and have had some issues with resources. It is nginx / mod_passenger. When I run top, it looks like this:

[image]

I'm obviously concerned about the memory consumption but should this be causing issues. Would it make sense to just make it a 1GB, 2GB, or 4GB and see if that makes it work better? Is there a location for ideal baselines?

thx

edit - hard to read the top, just copy url and post in new browser window to make it more legible. thx in advance for any help

Answer (score 0):

I have a small application running on a 512MB shared host using nginx/unicorn and I see a similar picture. It works more or less ok but if you are planning on doing things like image resizing with CarrierWave you might not have too good of a time.

My main application has about 1.5-2 million page views per week and that is using about 3GB with things running like delayed_job, faye pub/sub, memcached, monitoring, etc.

So I would suggest, that 512MB is really the absolute minimum unless you want to spend hours and hours on optimising your app.